# List index out of range - Python

Tags: python, parsing

I'm writing a short code (my first in python) to filter a large table.

```
import sys

gwas_annot = open('gwascatalog.txt').read()
gwas_entry_list = gwas_annot.split('\n')[1:-1]

# paste line if has value
for lines in gwas_entry_list:
    entry_notes = lines.split('\t')
    source_name = entry_notes[7]
    if 'omega-6' in source_name:
        print(entry_notes)
```

Basically I want to take the 'gwascatalog' table, parse it into lines and columns, search column 7 for a string ('omega-6' in this case) and if it contains it, print the entire line.

Right now it prints all the rows to the console but won't let me paste it into another file. It also gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "gwas_parse.py", line 9, in <module><br>
    source_name = entry_notes[7]<br>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Unsure why there is an error. Anything obvious to fix?

Edit: Adding snippet from data.

[image]

Comment: simple way to solve your problem is `print  entry_notes` before you try to index. without seeing the data you are trying to parse it is impossible to tell you why it errors other than you don't have 8 elements in your sublist `entry_notes`  at least once.

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: Just check how many entries you have `len(entry_notes)`. Maybe some rows have less than 8 entries.

Comment: Sorry guys still trying to get the post readable I'm pretty green. The table has about 30 columns so it should definitely have more than 8 elements. Will try to check length now.

Comment: fyi I just edited and removed the "code snippet" thing, since this is python and not html

Comment: Can you provide example of the input file?

Comment: "add print statements" is the best solution to all beginner python problems

Comment: How many columns do you have? Your list starts at [0] so [7] is column 8....

Comment: You need to add something that can be copy pasted and adding the output of `print(repr(entry_notes ))` will also help. Put the print before the indexing

Answer (score 2):

You can secure yourself by checking the length of the list first.

```
if len(entry_notes) > 7:
    source_name = entry_notes[7]
```

Comment: Added this exactly where you said.

Worked perfectly thank you very much.

Comment: @BananaMannock, you will lose data if there are lines less than 8 items, you should figure out why you are getting the error not just mask it .

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I assumed data is always in the seventh column regardless of the length. Question didn't say anything like "if length is less than 7, value is in the 6th column etc."

Comment: @ozgur, that does not mean there is not a bug somewhere else and data is not being lost. The OP obviously expects the value to be there so there is obviously something not right.

Comment: In this particular instance losing lines with less than 8 items is preferable.

However there actually shouldn't be any lines with less than 8 given the data I'm using. Would an alternate solution just be to search the entire line for the string and then print it? That seems line it would solve my issue and give me greater output.

Comment: @BananaMannock, that is my point,  if you don't expect there to be less than 8 then there is a bug in your code.  You need to figure out why it is happening not ignore it. If you have `30 columns` you need to figure out where the other 23+ went. Are you sure the file is tab delimited?

Comment: @BananaMannock. If you add the repr output of entry_notes just before your code errors then it will make it clear what it is that is going wrong.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham spot on. Did a field count and there is no lines below 8 columns (except the last line which is not used in my python script ofc). Yes it is tab delimited, downloaded from source and checked in excel.

Comment: I got it. There was an extra line added on the bottom after the usual final line. So in removing one there was still an empty line at the bottom. In setting the split to 'gwas_entry_list = gwas_annot.split('\n')[1:-2]' it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The list index out of range could be that you hit a row (line) where there are less than 7 columns.

```
    # index      0      1     2       3      4      5      6       (... no 7)
columnsArray = ['one', 'two','three','four','five','six', 'seven']
```

So here, if you ask for array[7], you get a "list index out of range" error because the line that the for loop is currently on only goes up to index 6.

The error tells you it happens at "line 9", which is where "source_name = entry_notes[7]". I would suggest printing out the number of columns for each row on the table. You might notice that somewhere you have 7 columns instead of 8. I also think you mean to say column 8, but position(or index 7), since counting in python starts at 0.

Maybe add another "if" to only look for lines that have a len() of 8 or more.